# LDAP Implementation in .net

Tags: .net, ldap

We're looking at implementing a new project that will use LDAP as it's security data store. What I'm looking for is a .net based implementation of the LDAP protocol. To be clear, I know about active directory, and I don't want a .net wrapper for active directory. What I'm looking for is an LDAP implementation in .net as there are plenty around in java, but I'm yet to come across a .net implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Novell [LDAP library](http://forge.novell.com/modules/xfcontent/downloads.php/ldapcsharp). (Guide article [here](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/11204.html#3.1.1))

Answer (score 11):

> In the .NET Framework 2.0, Microsoft
>   added features to its
>   System.DirectoryServices and provided
>   two new namespaces:
>   System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory
>   and
>   System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.
>   (We will refer to these as the
>   ActiveDirectory namespace and the
>   Protocols namespace, respectively,
>   throughout this article.) The
>   ActiveDirectory namespace introduced a
>   wealth of new classes for strongly
>   typed management of directory
>   infrastructure-level components, such
>   as servers, domains, forests, schema,
>   and replication. **The Protocols
>   namespace went in a different
>   direction, providing an alternative
>   API for programming Lightweight
>   Directory Access Protocol (LDAP). This
>   worked directly with the Windows LDAP
>   subsystem (wldap32.dll), skipping over
>   the ADSI COM interop layer entirely**

The .NET 3.5 [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) wraps " Active Directory Domain Services, the local Security Account Manager (SAM) data store on every Windows computer, and the relatively new Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services"